# How to append two rows into a single data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to append two row values of two data frames, creating a single data frame and displaying it in a row using R

**df1:**

```
Customer Names
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD.
ADCHEM
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA)
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA)
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA) PTY
Aurobindo Pharma (Australia) Pty
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA)PTY LTD
```

**df2**

```
    V1
1   tmax industrial 
2   tmax industrial 
3   adchem
4   adchem  
5   adchem   
6   aurobindo pharma  
7   aurobindo pharma  
8   aurobindo pharma  
9   aurobindo pharma   
10  aurobindo pharma
```

My **output** must look like this:

```
Customer Names                          V1
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD                    tmax industrial     
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD.                   tmax industrial     
ADCHEM                                  adchem  
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA)                      adchem      
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD              adchem      
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA)            aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA) PTY        aurobindo pharma    
Aurobindo Pharma (Australia) Pty        aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD     aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA)PTY LTD      aurobindo pharma
```

Using a for loop I have done it as

```
for (n in seq_len(nrow(grp1))) {
    print(grp1[n,]+','+grp2[n,]+'\n')  
}
```

but this is throwing an error.

Comment: `paste0(grp1[n,],",",grp2[n,],"\n")`. You can't add (`+`) character values in R, you have to `paste()` them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the error mentioned by @MrFlick, what you need is simply

```
output <- cbind(df1, df2)
```